# Remove XFCE4 bottom panel through terminal?

Tags: xfce, panel

Is there any way to remove XFCE4 bottom panel through terminal command only?

Comment: You should be able to use `xfconf-query` (https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/xfconf-query).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove it by:
`killall xfce4-panel`.

Alternatively you can adjust the settings so that it autohides when it is not in use. Should be able to right click > edit settings on it I believe